# YouTube Embed feature for looping single videos isn't working

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

Loop feature is not working.[Example](https://www.youtube.com/embed/X03jlFijeQ0?autoplay=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&fs=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&loop=1)

Answer (score 2):

Only a playlist can loop.
As such, there is a workaround by creating a playlist of the video.

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/X03jlFijeQ0?playlist=X03jlFijeQ0&autoplay=1&controls=0& modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&loop=1
```

You are welcome to test and play with it [here](http://www.myonlinelocation.com/YouTube_Play/youtube_embeded_player/)

Also note that you need to set `rel=0` as well.

Comment: I was missing the rel=0, so very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the iframe tag you can use, this is just your video in 'VIDOE_ID' & put repetable video id in 'REPEAT_VIDEO_ID_AGAIN'. It will work 100%.

```html
<iframe width="600" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDOE_ID?rel=0&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;playlist=REPEAT_VIDEO_ID_AGAIN" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```